# Вопрос про mapActions во vueX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Сейчас у меня есть методы которые увеличивают/уменьшают count по клику на кнопку, вызываются методы, в которых через `this.$store.dispatch` обрабатываются `action`. Но, как тоже самое провернуть если использовать импортированный `mapActions` ведь просто ...mapActions(['название']), не является методом. Подскажите как реализовать, чтоб тот же функционал остался, но с использованием `mapActions`

```
<template>
   <div>
      <p>{{ `Счетчик: ${count}` }}</p>
      <button @click="neg" class="btn-negative" type="button">-</button>
      <button @click="pos" class="btn-positive" type="button">+</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

   export default {
      computed: {
         count() {
           return this.$store.state.count
         },
      },
      methods: { 
         pos() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('positCount')
         },
         neg() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('negativeCount')
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Счетчик: {{ count }}</p>
    <button @click="() => negativeCount()" class="btn-negative" type="button">-</button>
    <button @click="() => positCount()" class="btn-positive" type="button">+</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    computed: {
      count() {
        return this.$store.state.count;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'positCount',
        'negativeCount',
      ]),
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @salco202020, пожалуйста. Вопросов нет, понятны принцип деструктуризации и причина использования стрелочных функций в шаблоне?

Comment: вроде как да, мы вызываем ее. Правда я сделал немного по другому, создал 2 метода и в самих методах вызвал через this.positCount() , лично мне так более удобно, в плане понимания кода) Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @salco202020, не потому что "вызываем" - вот так `@click="positCount"` тоже работало бы... но работало бы иначе: с нежелательным эффектом передачи `Event`-инстанса в действие payload'ом :) Метод для избавления от такой бяки это тоже нормальное решение, конечно. Еще можно и `@click="positCount()"`, вью по идее выполнит что-то типа `.bind` запомнив что обработчик надо без аргумента вызывать, но такая запись выглядит неоднозначно для js-программиста (будто мы результат вызова используем, хотя на самом деле нет).

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение) Но, моих знаний пока не достаточно чтоб осознать все написанное))